# For each loop, reading a line

Tags: java

```
for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine())
```

I know about for each loop but little confused in starting and ending, I know that `br.readline()` read the text file as per line.

Comment: So, whats your question?

Comment: That's not a `For-Each` loop, but a standard `For` loop.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the question is but ....

```
for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
    // do loop
}
```

is the same as

```
String line = br.readLine();
while(line != null) {
    // do loop
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

However I prefer

```
for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
   // do loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`For` loop statements in `Java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) are defined as (C&P):

```
for (<initialization>; <termination>; <increment>) {
    statement(s)
}
```

When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:

- The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
- When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
- The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

So, in your expression, you are initializing a String:

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

and the loop will end when this will not be true:

```
line != null;
```

that is: after you do

```
line = br.readLine())
```

and get `null`.